# iOS: How can I reuse UIViews built from a nib?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, nib

Situation:

- ReusableView.h
- ReusableView.m
- ReusableView.xib
- ViewController.h
- ViewController.m
- ViewController.xib

ReusableView is kind of basic template that I want to use as background across several ViewControllers. I tried using ReusableView as the ViewControllers view but it does not get loaded. What am I missing here? Is this possible at all (it SHOULD be, no)?

EDIT

After further investigation I found that my ReusableView IS instanciated with ViewController. It is available in viewDidLoad. But the Outlets of the ReusableView that are defined in it's nib are not connected. All IBOutlets are null.

I think this is because the ReusableViews initWithCoder method is called with the UINibDecoder of ViewController. How can I change that?

Comment: How are you loading it? It's perfectly possible to create a custom view for a view controller.

Comment: I was expecting the NIB to load it automatically via initWithCoder which is not the case... I also tried using this approach: https://blog.compeople.eu/apps/?p=142 but it failed because of ARC.

Comment: And have you tried fixing it to make it work with ARC?

Comment: They tried and they weren't able to. So I assume I won't be either :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `ReusableView` as the base template for the other `viewControllers`, then in that case, you can inherit the other view controllers from the `ReusableView` and then use the properties of the `ReusableView` in all of the other view controllers that you have created .